# Free tool to connect to mondrian/olap and view pivot-table + charts on my website

Tags: open-source, jasper-reports, pivot-table, pentaho, mondrian

I played with few open source BI projects: Pentaho, JasperSoft, icCube or SpagoBI. I managed to fill them with my data and view some reports or do analysis. But now the thing i really need is to skip their interfaces and call just MDX queries with some filters to Mondrian server and view data on my website with my own NAVIGATION. Something like MDX viewer.

E.G. On my website I've got around 10000 items somehow embedded in the vertical navigation menu hierarchy (impossible to make analysis view to all of them separately) and I want to view pivottable and charts for every item - based on the item selected I would call an MDX query and apply the filter ('where' with selected item). The thing is, i dont need to slice and dice there, just drilldown.

I suppose i need some alternatives to JPivot, but really running like embedded apps not whole report makers. Something like OpenI, but its not any more distributed like standalone platform yet like plugin for Pentaho or JasperSoft, again. icCube tends to provide JS library to cover such functionality, but due to comments doesn't seem to be for free use.

Comment: [Web Pivot Table](http://webpivottable.com) is exactly this kind of tool. Here is [demo](http://webpivottable.com/demo) and [documents](http://webpivottable.com/documents).

Answer (score 3):

Saiku might suit your needs.
It works with Penthao BI Server fine as a plugin.

http://analytical-labs.com/

Comment: Tnanks for reply. I noticed the product before, but can u suggest me how i can run SAVED query on my own web and filter it?

Comment: Saiku is made up of 2 parts, the UI and the server. You can talk to the server via REST and do everything like opening saving and executing reports.  Check in with the dev guys on ##saiku on the Freenode IRC channel - they're always keen to help out, and the product is geared from the ground up for this sort of integration.

Comment: Yeah, spoke to the guys. They were nice but +/-drilldown doesnt seem to appear in next releases. So JPivot is obviously the only one free tool on the market that fits +/-drilldown requirments.. Correct me if im wrong.